# Azure SQL table exists but iOS Swift MSClient returns "Table does not exist"?

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I created a new Azure SQL table "BlockyLike" in my existing Azure SQL Service using Azure Data Studio. This new table works well in Azure Data Studio, I have populated with 5000 of data entries, I can select query or insert data, everything works well.

[image]

However, in my existing iOS Swift app, trying to querying or inserting in this table always returns the following error:

```
Error: Table 'BlockyLike' does not exist.
```

I double checked the table name, it was correctly spelled, just like how I was using other tables. Same existing common Azure SQL query method, every detail is checked.

```
static func tableQuery(_ tableName: String, predicate: NSPredicate, queryCallBack: @escaping ([AnyObject]?) -> ()) {
    guard let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
        let client = delegate.client else { return }
    
    // condition
    let table = client.table(withName: tableName)
    table?.read(with: predicate) { result, error in
        if let err = error {
            print("Query failed: ==>", err.localizedDescription)
            queryCallBack(nil)
            
        } else if let items = result?.items {
            // print("Query succeeded!")
            queryCallBack(items as [AnyObject]?)
        }
    }
}
```

I've been trying to solve this issue, I tried the following:

1. Verify table name spelling.
2. Verify table is active on Azure Data Studio. i.e. Can query and update table.
3. Rebooted my Azure SQL service several times.
4. Completely delete app and reinstall app just in case if it has any cache for tables.
5. Compared the new table with existing table, verify all attributes are the same with existing tables.
6. Verified that the service user has permission to read/write this table.

What can I try next?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1182339/how-to-fix-azure-sql-table-exists-but-querying-in

Comment: Could you check if the code run on the same SQL server/database

Comment: Yes, all these tables are under the same database, and connection to database is initialized right after app launched.

Comment: Try changing some data in other sql tables and check if the same is reflecting in the app too.

Comment: all other sql tables in the same database works correctly, they are already being used in the app and works correctly.